# Using Jquery to sort based on value in a div

Tags: jquery, sorting, xhtml

So I am writing a program that needs to be sorted based off the contents of a div.  What I'd like is two things:

1. The program gets sorted out by items of a grandchild div which is hidden by default.  The 'weight value' is what I wish to sort by (and if it's below a certain point move it to the other table)
2. When the items are sorted, items that have some kind of override in them get sorted into another table that is "unlikely to be called"

So here's my code at present:

```
<div id="likelyToBeCalled">
    <div class="likelyOddHeader" id="Test1">
        <div class="likelyOddA">Test1</div>
        <div class="likelyOddB"><img src="image002.png"/></div>
        <div class="timeZone">West</div>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden">
            <div class="weight">Weight:56</div>
            <div class="values">Value1: Value Here.  Value 2: Value Here. Value 3: Value Here.  Value 4:  Value here.  Value5: Value here. <br />
                                            DbValue1: 123, DbValue2: 1234, DbValue3, 123456 DbValue4: 123, DbValue5: 1234, DbValue6, 123456</div>
            <div class="overrides">Overrides: 0</div>
    </div>
...More divs / values here

<div id="unlikelyToBeCalled">
    <div class="likelyOddHeader" name="Test3">
        <div class="likelyOddA">Test3</div>
        <div class="likelyOddB"><img src="image002.png"/></div>
        <div class="timeZone">West</div>
    </div>
...More divs / values here
```

So far I've been trying to do this with just jQuery and it hasn't been going all that well. I have no idea how to handle the 'if' logic or how to handle a sort, and I'm still struggling to move from one area to another...

The code I've been trying involves a submit button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$("input.buttonDhide").click(function(){ $(".row").find(".left").hide("slow"); });
)};
)};
</script>
```

Edit:  Note the above code was really just to see if I could select an element that way and it didn't work at all.

Edit:  Changed markup to use classes as I had mistakenly duplicated id's, all set there now.

Comment: Your html is invalid, duplicate `id`a are not allowed, use a `class`.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using a table (it seems like tabular data), then you can use jQuery sorting: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: I'm using a div in place of a table and basically doing the same thing:

Comment: .left{
 display: table-cell;
}

.right{
 display: table-cell;
}

.middle{
 display: table-cell;
}

.row{
  display: table-row;
  height:45px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

Comment: You're duplicating IDs, this is invalid HTML. I'd consider adding this data into a JavaScript array of some kind rather than hiding it in markup.

Comment: I've actually just gone through and fixed the html markup so it's using classes and not ID's

Comment: instead of using classes (which may have unexpected side-effects) it's much better to use data-X attributes (like data-id).

Answer (score 1):

To me, this seems like a perfect candidate for [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/).  Rather than trying to find some element by it's class or data-attr with jQuery to sort, you could be directly sorting a javascript array (ko.observableArray) that's bound to your html structure.

[Here's a hastily thrown together jsdfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7zDp/) showing one way you could do this.  I'm not sure if you're wanting to check on the weight or overrides variable, so I just used (if overrides == 1).  You can change that pretty easily, i.e. (if weight < 10). I highly recommend you go through some of the Knockout.js tutorials. IMO, it mucho kicksos assos...Gorlami!

I'll include the code here just in case. Keep in mind this could and probably should be cleaned up a little:

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="with: likelyToBeCalled">
    <div data-bind="with: likelyOddHeader">
        <div data-bind="text: likelyOddA"></div>
        <div><img data-bind="attr: { src: likelyOddB }" alt="" /></div>
        <div data-bind="text: timeZone"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="foreach: hidden">
        <div data-bind="text: 'Weight: ' + weight"></div>
        <div data-bind="text: 'Values: ' + values"></div>
        <div data-bind="text: 'Overrides: ' + overrides"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<p>
    <button data-bind="click: buttonClick">Sort likely to be called</button>
</p>

<div data-bind="with: unlikelyToBeCalled">
    <div data-bind="with: likelyOddHeader">
        <div data-bind="text: likelyOddA"></div>
        <div><img data-bind="attr: { src: likelyOddB }" alt="" /></div>
        <div data-bind="text: timeZone"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="foreach: hidden">
        <div data-bind="text: 'Weight: ' + weight"></div>
        <div data-bind="text: 'Values: ' + values"></div>
        <div data-bind="text: 'Overrides: ' + overrides"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JS (Don't forget to include knockout.js):

```
var viewModel = {
    likelyToBeCalled: {
        likelyOddHeader: {
            likelyOddA: "Test1",
            likelyOddB: "image001.png",
            timeZone: "West"
        },
        hidden: ko.observableArray([
            { weight: 56, values: "your values string 1", overrides: 1 },
            { weight: 20, values: "your values string 2", overrides: 0 },
            { weight: 12, values: "your values string 3", overrides: 0 },
            { weight: 16, values: "your values string 4", overrides: 1 }
        ])
    },
    unlikelyToBeCalled: {
        likelyOddHeader: {
            likelyOddA: "Test2",
            likelyOddB: "image002.png",
            timeZone: "East"
        },
        hidden: ko.observableArray([
            { weight: 1, values: "your values string 4", overrides: 1 }
        ])
    },
    buttonClick: function () {
        var likely = viewModel.likelyToBeCalled;
        var unlikely = viewModel.unlikelyToBeCalled;

        for (var i in likely.hidden()) {
            if (likely.hidden()[i].overrides == 1) {
                unlikely.hidden.push(likely.hidden()[i]);
                likely.hidden.remove(likely.hidden()[i]);
            }
        }

        likely.hidden.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.weight > b.weight ? 1 : -1;
        });
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```